# Ternary operator and covariant coercion

Tags: c#

I declare the variable,

```
IList<int> list;
```

then I write the statement,

```
if(true)
{
    list = new List<int>();
}
else
{
    list = new int[0];
}
```

I have trivial and pointless code that compiles without warning. If I write the statement,

```
list = true ? new List<int>() : new int[0];
```

I get the compiler warning,

> There is no implicit conversion between 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' and 'int[]'

Why does the ternary operator have this limitation? Both `List<int>` and `int[]` implement `IList<int>`.

---

### Post Answer

From section **7.14 Conditional Operator** of the C# 5.0 Specification

> The second and third operands, x and y, of the ?: operator control the type of the conditional expression.

1. If x has type X and y has type Y then

   - If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from X to Y, but not from Y to X, then Y is the type of the conditional expression.
   - If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from Y to X, but not from X to Y, then X is the type of the conditional expression.
   - Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.
2. If only one of x and y has a type, and both x and y, of are implicitly convertible to that type, then that is the type of the conditional expression.
3. Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a problem with the assignment to `list`.  It's a problem with the expression `true ? new List<int>() : new int[0]`.  This expression is not legal under any circumstances.

If you refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), you'll find this information.

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

That's not true in this case.

Comment: The problem being, `List<T>` and `T[]` are not implicitly convertible, either way. However, they are both implicitly convertible to `IList<T>`, the type of the assignee. The compiler does not perform this analysis.

Comment: Yes, the compiler doesn't perform that analysis, as it would violate the specification of the language.

Comment: Agreed, the rules are specified in section **7.14 Conditional Operator** of the C# 5.0  specification.

Answer (score 2):

Both `List<int>` and `int[]` implement a lot of things (`IEnumerable<int>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<int>`, etc.). It's hard for the compiler to know which one you mean without giving it a hint:

```
list = true ? (IList<int>) new List<int>() : new int[0];
```

Remember that expressions are evaluated from the inside out. So your ternary operator is evaluated prior to the compiler looking at what you're trying to assign it to. So there has to be some kind of implicit conversion available from the type on one side to the type on the other side.

In your if/else example, you're effectively casting `List<int>` to an `IList<int>` as its own operation, without trying to combine it with the `int[]` first.

Comment: The compiler works it out in your corrected statement. However, the compilers analysis is limited to an implicit conversion check between the first and second expressions.